# Etimología de "pava" como nombre para la coliflor

Tags: etimología, españa, comida

En la Región de Murcia (y supongo que en zonas aledañas) hay un plato muy típico, que es el **arroz con pava**:

[image]

Básicamente es una paella de verduras, a veces con bacalao. Pero el nombre no es porque lleve además carne de pavo hembra, no; **lo de "con pava" es porque lleva *coliflor***.

Los recetarios que se pudieren encontrar con una simple [búsqueda en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=arroz%20con%20pava) dirán que el motivo es que por estas tierras a la coliflor se le dice "pava", aunque yo la verdad es que solo he visto usar esa denominación cuando se habla de este plato en concreto; nunca vi a ningún agricultor hablar de "plantar pava" o de "regar las pavas", ni ninguna lonja donde las cajas que descargaban los camiones pusieran "pava" en vez de "coliflor" (al contrario que, por ejemplo, ["alcaciles"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1aYBPWk) en vez de alcachofas o ["pésoles"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SnkrHDf) en lugar de guisantes).

Para más inri, en el DLE ninguna de las entradas para [**pava**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=pava) recoge su significado como "coliflor", así que no es de ayuda.

Mi pregunta es: aceptado el hecho de que en el sureste de España a la coliflor se le dice "pava", al menos en algunos contextos... **¿cuál es el origen de este nombre?** ¿Es quizá un arabismo o un catalanismo, como los ejemplos antes citados de *alcacil* y *pésol*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo poco que he podido encontrar, parece que el "arroz con pava" debe su nombre a lo que se conoce como "pava de huerta", que sería una traducción literal de la expresión catalana (o valenciana tal vez) "indiota d'horta", siendo "indiota" una palabra usada para "pava" (el animal).

Te pongo algunos textos encontrados (negritas mías):

> També hi ha paelles, paelletes i arrossos vegetals- els arrossos “pobres” ja esmentats-, com els de créixens de Mallorca, amb espinacs, amb faves, amb castanyes, amb ceba- un clàssic valencià-, el de carabassa, amb penques, **amb “pava de huerta” o indiota d’ horta (coliflor)**, amb carxofes i pèsols- molt típics d’ Alacant i Catalunya-, amb cigrons, amb fesols, amb llenties, amb fesols de careta… <sub>[[Fuente](https://blocs.mesvilaweb.cat/jaumefabrega/?p=267975).]</sub>

La verdad es que este texto no me deja claro si la expresión en catalán es traducción de la castellana o al revés. De la misma web pero otra entrada es este:

> Alguns d’ aquests arrossos “de crisi” reben noms humorístics com l’ ”Arròs amb indiota d’ horta”, que és un arròs valencià amb coliflor. <sub>[[Fuente](https://blocs.mesvilaweb.cat/jaumefabrega/?p=242648).]</sub>

En este caso sí que parece darse un origen valenciano al nombre. El texto habla de arroces "pobres" (para tiempos de crisis) que se hacen exclusivamente con verduras. Por tanto parece que el nombre vendría dado como para simular que el arroz tiene algo de carne, llamando "pava de huerta" a la coliflor, aunque de momento ignoro el motivo exacto, si es que lo hay más allá del mero afán eufemístico.

Answer (score 1):

No podía encontrar mucho sobre sus raíces, pero parece que viene específicamente de la aldea de La Arboleja:

> [image]
>
> - [*Diccionario incompleto de la Región de Murcia: textos para la radio*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7E-oAy9lancC&pg=PA132&dq=pava+coliflor), Francisco Alemán Saínz
> - [*Vocabulario Del Dialecto Murciano: Con un Estudio Preliminar y un Apéndice de Documentos Regionales*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rSRKAAAAYAAJ&dq=pava), Justo García Soriano (1932)

La [*Revista Murciana de Antropología - El cuento folclórico en Cartagena*](https://digitum.um.es/jspui/bitstream/10201/41706/1/El%20cuento%20folcl%C3%B3rico%20en%20Cartagena.pdf), por Anselmo J. Sánchez Ferra, sugiere en una note de pie que puede ser relacionado con [el otro significado](https://www.saberespractico.com/curiosidades/diccionario-murciano-espanol-por-orden-alfabetico/) de *pava* en murciano:

> Pava es también nombre aplicado en la región a la coliflor, 
>   planta cuya cocción arroja un aroma desagradable que tal vez puede haber sugerido la asociación pava/pedo; pero el D.R.A.E. apunta para este término la acepción de “fuelle grande usado en ciertos hornos metálicos”, y el sonido del aire exhalado por el fuelle plantea otra posible explicación para este significado.
>
> (paj. 240, nota 30)